# How do I know which month is not exist in a table date column from connection date (registered date)?

Tags: php, mysql, date

Well, I have 2 mysql tables :

1) clients

```
client_id    conn_date       monthly_bill
=========================================
10            2016-06-01     700.00
11            2016-08-30     650.00
12            2016-08-30     1000.00 
13            2016-07-01     700.00
```

2) clients_pay_bill

```
cbp_id   client_id   bill_month
===============================
1        10          2016-08-30         
2        11          2016-08-12
3        12          2016-08-08
```

In `clients` table `conn_date` column is the date when user first register or connection date.

In `clients_pay_bill` table `bill_month` column shows that which month client pay his bill.

Now in a **current month** I want to show the total due bill from **connection date** to **current date**.

For ex : In `clients_pay_bill` table `clients_id = 10` is only paid this **2016-08-30**  month bill. But didn't paid this **2016-06-08 and 2016-07-08** months bill. So his due is now = 1400 because his monthly bill is 700.

I can't imagine how the mysql query should look like ! How can I do this ?

Update :

[image]

Comment: `month(timestamp)` will give you the month of a date column. I don't see any column with paid/unpaid though so I don't know how you are going to do that.

Comment: which month user is not paid is determine by which month is not exist in `clients_pay_bill` `bill_month` column

Comment: Why not just have a `datepaid` column?

Comment: `month_bill` is that column in which month clients is paid

Answer (score 1):

```
select C.client_id,C.monthly_bill,
       (
        PERIOD_DIFF(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from CURDATE()),
                    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from C.conn_date))+1
        -
        count(P.bill_month)
       )*C.monthly_bill as Need_many
  from clients C
  left join clients_pay_bill P
    on P.client_id=C.client_id and P.bill_month<date_format(curdate(),'%Y-%m-01')
 group by C.client_id
```

Function `PERIOD_DIFF()` return the number of months between periods (current month and connected date). `Count()` rows in clients_pay_bill return count of payd month. The difference between these values is the count of unpaid months.

Comment: Okey, let me try with this.

Comment: I have existing query to show all clients. So can I add this code to existing query or I have to use this in existing query while loop ?

Comment: @shibbirahmed This query displays the difference on all clients, add the missing fields in the sample

Comment: well, I am using it in while loop and it's showing me different amount.  e.g : a clients `conn_date` is 2016-08-30 and it's due is showing me 2100 !

Comment: and I have changed this line :  `on P.client_id= '$client_id' `

Comment: @shibbirahmed No. `ON` clause must by unchanged !!!. Add `Where` clause if need filter clients

Comment: I changed it but a user `conn_date` is 2016-06-01 and he paid 2016-07-01 to 2016-12-01. Now in current month 2016-08-30 its showing me due is : -2100. His monthly bill is 700

Comment: But it's should be show me 2016-06-01 due bill and advance bill

Comment: @shibbirahmed Answer updated. Added `and P.bill_month<date_format(curdate(),'%Y-%m-01')` to `ON` clause

Comment: Well, according to my last example clients : It's should be show me only 700 due because he didn't paid 2016-06-01 month bill. ( here day is not fact ) Today : 2016-08-31 and it's should be show me 700 due of 2016-06-01 month and if there are any further month bill is paid it's should be show me advance. E.g 3500 from

Comment: @shibbirahmed Modify own selection criteria in the request for your task. remove the "group by" and group functions, to see which rows have been received and which are not.